# VS2010 ItemTemplate throws exception until project properties opened

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, exception, itemtemplate

Okay, so I wrote a few custom ItemTemplates for VS2010 that implement IWizard in VB.NET (4.0). Straight forward enough.

They work during my testing, but when someone else deploys and attempts to use any of them, Visual Studio throws an incredibly generic `Exception has been thrown by a target of invocation` error.

Stranger still, after they open up the project properties and try again... they work. Without changing anything.

Anyone have any clue what is going on? Or perhaps even just a way of getting VS to give me a more specific error? I already tried `devenv.exe /log` but nothing out of the ordinary was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I discovered the problem was that an external assembly being used wasn't loading for some reason. I used [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) in order to observe closer and found out that Visual Studio isn't loading the DLL from the location I set in the References settings. Instead, it is only looking in the default locations (such as PrivateAssemblies). The problem still goes away after viewing the project properties, which doesn't make any sense to me, but at least now I know the problem.

My solution for now is to just deploy my DLL into PrivateAssemblies and the problem goes away.